# Azure Data Factory changes my date string to another format

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using a dataset in Azure Data Factory to retrieve data from an API, and the relative URL is a concat of both static text and parameters for timestamp from and timestamp to, so I am able to query the date periods dynamically.

My TimestampFrom and TimestampTo parameters are string parameters:

[Dataset parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeEuG.png)

This is how I have defined the relative URL in the dataset (dynamic content):

[Dynamic content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RbEG.png)

But when the API request is made, I get an error because ADF for some reason changes the date format of the timestamp strings, even though they are defined as string:
[API Return error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxro5.png)

Thus the API returns an error stating that the format is not correct.

If I change the entire URL to a concat of static strings, it works fine:

[Using static string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGbBP.png)

Comment: Can you show how you are populating the DataSet parameters?

Comment: @JoelCochran I just keep the default values for the DataSet parameters, the error appears when debugging

Answer (score 0):

As you said when you are passing dataset parameters values through dynamic value it is changing the Format and if you are passing static value, it works.

so, you can define the required date format you want in Dynamic value itself using **formatDateTime** with format `'yyyy-MMThh:mm:ssZ'`

So, the expression will be as below:

```json
@concat('observations/ve.jsonld?elements=air_temperature& levels=default&referencetime=',formatDateTime(dataset().TimestamFrom,'yyyy-MMThh:mm:ssZ'),'/',formatDateTime(dataset().TimestampTo,'yyyy-MMThh:mm:ssZ'), '&sources=', dataset().Source, '&timeoffsets=default& timeresolutions=PT1H')
```

You will get relative URL as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not passing any value, but using the default value that is assigned to the parameters which is a date on the correct format but stored as a string (the parameter is data type string). That's why I find it so confusing that ADF apparently changes the string value to another string value as if it was a date.

Comment: When you pass the value with appropriate format it will detect the type and convert it.